# Looking for feedback on OOP for a trading bot on Kraken

Tags: python, object-oriented, api

I'm trying to build a Kraken portfolio bot and started out with a simple layout for loading the balances. If possible, I would like to get some feedback on this initial design.

The API key provided is only to read funds so don't bother to try out something else.

After this, the idea is to set one account as the main account, which will serve as an example. The bot will recreate any action on main to others. Essentially just a copy trader bot! But first I would like to know if this design is a good start.

```
import krakenex
from pykrakenapi import KrakenAPI 
import json

api = krakenex.API()
kraken = KrakenAPI(api)

class Database:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.accounts = []
    
    def add(self, account):
        self.accounts.append(account)
        
    def create_backup(self):
        json.dump(self, open('backup.json', 'w'), default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
        print("Created new backup.")

class Account:
    '''Creates account with credentials that will be passed to a Portfolio'''
    def __init__(self, name, api_key, api_sec, email) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.api_sec = api_sec
        self.api_path = self.create_txt_keys()
        self.email = email

        # Loads balances as dict and sets as attributes
        self.portfolio = Portfolio(**KrakenLoader(self).get_dict_of_assets())
        
    def create_txt_keys(self) -> string:
        '''Creates txt file with space seperated credentials for the Kraken API'''
        filepath = f'api_keys/{self.name}_api_keys.txt'
        f= open(filepath , "w+")
        f.write(f"{self.api_key}\n{self.api_sec}")
        f.close()
        print(f"Created file for {self.name} with api_keys.")
        return filepath
           
class Portfolio(Account):
    '''Creates portfolio for the given Account'''
    def __init__(self, **data) -> None:
        for key in data:
            setattr(self, key, data[key])
        #e.g.
        #self.XETH = 0.1
        #self.CRV = 20
        
class KrakenLoader:
    '''Loads api_key and loads asset balances which is used by Portfolio'''
    def __init__(self, account) -> None:
        ## Loads api key of account by provided path of credentials (part of API)
        self.account = account
        api.load_key(self.account.api_path)
        
    def get_dict_of_assets(self) -> dict:
        '''Returns dict with with all balances, excluding dust'''    
        account_data = kraken.get_account_balance()
        balance = {}
        try:
            for index, vol in zip(account_data.index, account_data['vol']):
                ## Excludes dust balances
                if vol > 0.0001:
                    balance[index] = vol
                    # {'ZUSD': 78.2502, 'DOT.S': 0.05021271, 'ATOM': 1.0, 'LUNA': 1.05}
            print(f"Done loading all balances from {self.account.name}'s Kraken account.")
        except:
            print('Something went wrong.')
        return balance

database = Database()
user_1 = Account("user_1", "yoEU/6JE03CbzWV4DNKGCKRAWtOnfOK+ynIgv+dmdVmqWctAxGQnxEMj", "wCQiUzp3PuQkiWudFipxiqp2jcXWcpZ8QWMXXteHmbhuJzFf8dsv6QhOAu0T3jnI0NTO72I1XpQerRVqzNLjgA==", "user@protonmail.com")
database.add(user_1)

for account in database.accounts:
    print(account.portfolio.__dict__)

database.create_backup()
```

Answer (score 3):

What you have is needlessly complex. In general, I always start with just functions. If I need to manage state between functions, that might warrant the use of a class (or multiple classes, if it makes sense). In your case, the logic is simple enough to just use a single class:

```py
import json

import krakenex
from pykrakenapi import KrakenAPI


class Account:
    def __init__(self, name: str, email: str, api_key: str, api_secret: str) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.api = KrakenAPI(krakenex.API(api_key, api_secret))

    def get_account_balance(self) -> dict:
        account_data = self.api.get_account_balance()
        return dict(account_data[account_data["vol"] > 0.0001]["vol"])


with open("accounts.json") as fi:
    accounts = [Account(**d) for d in json.load(fi)]
```

Where `accounts.json` is:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "user_1",
        "email": "user1@protonmail.com",
        "api_key": "yoEU/6JE03CbzWV4DNKGCKRAWtOnfOK+ynIgv+dmdVmqWctAxGQnxEMj",
        "api_secret": "wCQiUzp3PuQkiWudFipxiqp2jcXWcpZ8QWMXXteHmbhuJzFf8dsv6QhOAu0T3jnI0NTO72I1XpQerRVqzNLjgA=="
    },
    {
        "name": "user_2",
        "email": "user2@protonmail.com",
        "api_key": "yoEU/6JE03CbzWV4DNKGCKRAWtOnfOK+ynIgv+dmdVmqWctAxGQnxEMj",
        "api_secret": "wCQiUzp3PuQkiWudFipxiqp2jcXWcpZ8QWMXXteHmbhuJzFf8dsv6QhOAu0T3jnI0NTO72I1XpQerRVqzNLjgA=="
    }
]
```

Here's example usage:

```py
for account in accounts:
    print(account.get_account_balance())
```

Which outputs:

```
{'DOT.S': 0.05168451, 'ZUSD': 0.0022, 'SGB': 0.14808087, 'LUNA': 1.05, 'ATOM': 2.4974, 'ZEUR': 11.3027}
{'ZUSD': 0.0022, 'DOT.S': 0.05168451, 'LUNA': 1.05, 'ATOM': 2.4974, 'SGB': 0.14808087, 'ZEUR': 11.3027}
```

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for the feedback! This sure looks much more elegant. If I understand you correctly, a more functional approach is the way to go instead of trying to "class" everything. I will take this with me in my future design. Have a good one, cheers.

Thanks, voters for enough karma to comment btw!